# Can I use CSS to specify classes to set by using selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, jquery-mobile

I want all of my JQuery Mobile pages to use the mini version of the input search fields when possible.

I look at the example pages and it's apparent that what I want is to set all elements with class `.ui-input-search` to also have assigned class `.ui-mini`.

Why this rather than just using the `data-mini="true"` attribute? Because specifying a `data-filter="true"` listview has JQM automatically generate the input search element: I don't get a chance to specify that I want the mini version of it.

Current solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () { $('.ui-input-search').addClass('ui-mini'); });
</script>
```

Is there a(n inherently more elegant) CSS solution? Something like

```
.ui-input-search {
  setClass(ui-mini); /* this line is pseudo-code */
}
```

Comment: your current solution seems to be the appropriate one... i do not know of any way to do this in CSS

Comment: Can you attach the jQuery mobile script to use the mini version of the fields with the `.ui-input-search`?  Seems silly to have to select by a class to attach a class to act on when there's already a class there to begin with.

Comment: @SurrealDreams What do you mean exactly? Wouldn't I have to find within the javascript code every instance of setting class `ui-input-search` and add to each of them the class `ui-mini`? What I just described sounds like a hack that will cause much pain and suffering later on.

Comment: I'm just wondering if you can't attach the mini input behavior to the `.ui-input-search` class - it's already there and it sounds like a suitable target to select.

Comment: Check out less: http://lesscss.org/

Comment: Toni beat me to it.  http://lesscss.org/  is the way to go for this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out less! I have seen it before but it didn't occur to me today that it would tackle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `document.ready` you can bind to the `pageinit` event for the specific pseudo-page on which the list-view with a search widget exists.

```
$(document).delegate('#some-page-id', 'pageinit', function () {
    $(this).find('.ui-input-search').addClass('ui-mini');
});
```

This is the "jQuery Mobile" way of binding event handlers, ensuring that it will function no matter the time-frame.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bHrJy/

Comment: Thanks for writing this answer! It prompted me to read http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/ and this has been quite enlightening.

Comment: That looks like an excellent guide, also check-out the jQuery Mobile documentation here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Suppose I wanted to apply this to all of my pseudo-pages, not just a specific one. Could I modify the first line to `$(document).delegate('.ui-page', ...`? Hmm. Then I'd have to change the rest of it too. I see what your code does. It cleverly only applies the class to the specific relevant `.ui-input-search`s on the pseudo-page that gets matched.

Comment: Yes, but no. The `.ui-page` class is added after the element is initialized; so to be safe you should use `[data-role="page"]` since that attribute is always present on the element: `$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageinit', function () {...});`

Comment: Didn't know jQ could handle that syntax. Cool. Thanks.

Comment: What if the HTML specified `<div data-role='page'>` (note single quotes)? Would `'[data-role="page"]'` still match it?

Comment: Yes, actually the double quotes in `[data-role="page"]` are CSS/query specific and are not necessary in this example, it's necessary when you have non-allowed characters in the value of the attribute, like a space. This would be invalid: `[data-role=attribute with spaces]`. That being said, you can use whatever style of quotes you want to use as long as they nest properly (or you have properly escaped any quotes necessary).

Comment: i.e. jQuery takes care of the parsing of the CSS selector string for me. Quite convenient, that.

Answer (score 0):

I'll always prefer CSS solutions to layout rather than javascript..

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="mini.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width:768px)"/>`

OR in a normal CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { 
    .ui-input-search {
        height: auto;
        width: 80px;
    }
}
```